# INDEX MATCH or VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP to find match among seven non-sequential cells

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I built this INDEX MATCH formula, but I assume there must be a more efficient excel function to solve this.

```
 =IF(INDEX($L3:$BA3,MATCH($H3,$L$1:$BA$1,0))>0,"CategoryGreaterThan0","CategoryIsZero")
```

I've only used INDEX MATCH when there is one exact match present.  As constructed, I believe -- though not certain -- that this draws upon the *first* match among 42 cells.  But that's already a waste because we know there are specifically only *seven cells of the 42* that we will *ever* want to look at.

So a simple IF/THEN function needs to reference seven non-sequential cells in the current row (and potentially reference seven or more non-sequential cells from row $1).

```
H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   AA  AB  AC  AD  AE  AF  AG  AH  AI  AJ  AK  AL  AM  AN  AO  AP  AQ  AR  AS  AT  AU  AV  AW  AX  AY  AZ  BA
Cat_Current             Cat_A   Cat_A   Cat_A   Cat_A   Cat_A   Cat_A   Cat_B   Cat_B   Cat_B   Cat_B   Cat_B   Cat_B   Cat_C   Cat_C   Cat_C   Cat_C   Cat_C   Cat_C   Cat_D   Cat_D   Cat_D   Cat_D   Cat_D   Cat_D   Cat_E   Cat_E   Cat_E   Cat_E   Cat_E   Cat_E   Cat_F   Cat_F   Cat_F   Cat_F   Cat_F   Cat_F   Cat_G   Cat_G   Cat_G   Cat_G   Cat_G   Cat_G
Cat_A               1                       0                       3                       1                       0                       1                       2
```

I want *only* to look in columns L, R, X, AD, AJ, AP, AV.

$H3 will match just one of $L$1, $R$1, $X$1, $AD$1, $AJ$1, $AP$1, $AV$1.
*The rest of $M$1:$BA$1 are irrelevant, as are $M3:$BA3.*

Suppose $H3 matches $AD$1,
then I check if $AD3>0, to produce "CategoryGreaterThan0" for true, "CategoryIsZero" for false.

Is there a smarter excel function that can look only at the seven cells I want, instead of all 42?

Comment: *"not sure it actually works properly"* is not a question. How do you want it to work and how does it work differently that you want?

Comment: I'm currently referencing 42 cells when I know seven specific cells are the only places I'll ever need to look.  What is the best function to achieve this? @A.S.H

Comment: hey @pnuts how bout taking back your -1?

Comment: much appreciated, @A.S.H.  goes a long way where I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add MOD(*column_num*, 6) to the column matching criteria. Your desired matching column numbers are 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42 and 48. Any matching column will have a MOD(column_num, 6) of zero.

```
=IF(INDEX($A3:$BA3, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(L:AV)/((L1:AV1=H3)*NOT(MOD(COLUMN(L:AV), 6))), 1)),"CategoryGreaterThan0","CategoryIsZero")
```

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H - I had a hard time with the dog's breakfast masquerading as sample data and had to write the formula blind. I had another look just now and I believe I added the correct criteria.

Comment: No INDEX is necessary because the OP wants the first match in columns L:AV on a six column stagger.

Comment: The first 6 is ignore errors. MOD(COLUMN(L:AV), 6) will return zero for matching columns on a 6 column stagger; NOT flips zero/false into one/true. All columns that don't return zero get flipped to zero resulting in a #DIV/0! error (wchihc hte first 6 ignores)

Comment: Okay, I follow this now.  That's a pretty great solution.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @jeeped Is it still best to start my INDEX at $A3 (and end at $BA3), even though I definitely won't need to look before $L3 (or after $AV3)?  Should I rewrite it to IF(INDEX($L3:$AV3,AGGREGATE...  ?

Comment: You can end it at AV3 but if you change both ends you will have to change COLUMN(L:AV) to COLUMN(A:AK) because then it is the **position within** L3:AV3. This way doesn't do any harm and the formula is easier to follow. You are never actually doing anything at all with A3:J3 or AW3:BA3. It could just as easily be ROW(3:3).

Comment: Okay, great.  Thanks very much @jeeped!  Your pooch's munchies are on me.